# Use of implicit function theorem in showing that $f(x) \leq a$ is a submanifold with boundary

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, morse-theory

This question comes from a statement in John Milnor's "Morse Theory" on page 4.

Let $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function on a manifold $M$. Milnor claims that if $a$ is not a critical value of $f$, then $M^a=\{x \in M \mid f(x) \leq a\}$ is a manifold-with-boundary, and that this "follows from the implicit function theorem."

Could someone make explicit to which function we're applying the implicit function theorem, and how the above statement follows?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* We need to exhibit a suitable atlas.
Recall what "is not a critical value" means. Infer from that which Jacobian might be invertible and from that get an idea how the IFT is applied.